# Excluding dependencies by webpack.externals prop causes `Object.defineProperty called on non-object` error

Tags: node.js, typescript, webpack, tampermonkey, userscripts

I'm building userscript boilerplate. This project relies on `tsyringe` and `reflect-metadata` packages.

I want them not to be included in resulting bundle, instead they should be loaded by userscript manager (e.g. Tampermonkey) by `@require` field on top of bundle header, fetching them from jsdelivr CDN.

The simplest solution is to use Webpack's `externals` property and pass package.json's `dependencies` prop contents there:

```js
...
externals: {
        ...Object.fromEntries(Object.keys(packageJson.dependencies).map(key => [key, key]))
    },
...
```

This works fine and removes `tsyringe` and `reflect-metadata` from the bundle correctly, also it builds fine.

But in runtimes, I encounter error: `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Object.defineProperty called on non-object`. And it leads me to this code in bundle:

```js
            /**
 * Minified by jsDelivr using Terser v5.13.1.
 * Original file: /npm/tsyringe@4.7.0/dist/cjs/index.js
 *
 * Do NOT use SRI with dynamically generated files! More information: https://www.jsdelivr.com/using-sri-with-dynamic-files
 */
            "use strict";
            Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { // the error is here
                value: !0
            });
```

How to fix the error? I tried `webpack-node-externals` package with no luck.

**webpack.config.ts**

```
const configCommon: Configuration = {
    //...
    },
    externals: {
        ...Object.fromEntries(Object.keys(packageJson.dependencies).map(key => [key, key]))
    },
    plugins: [
        // some custom plugins here
    ]
}
```

**tsconfig.json**

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES6",                                  
    "experimentalDecorators": true,                   
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,                    
    "module": "commonjs",                                
    "typeRoots": ["./node_modules/@types", "./src/types"],                                  
    "resolveJsonModule": true,                           
    "removeComments": true,                           
    "esModuleInterop": true,                             
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,            
    "strict": true,                                      
    "skipLibCheck": true                                 
  }
}
```

**package.json**

```json
{
  ...
  "dependencies": {
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "tsyringe": "^4.7.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: If you use `.map(key => [key, key])`, then webpack will try to use a `reflect-metadata` variable which isn't a valid var name. Specify `externals` manually instead based on what each `@require`d JS file exports.

Comment: @double-beep yep, already did this:

```typescript
externals: {
        "reflect-metadata": "reflect-metadata",
        "tsyringe": "tsyringe",
    },
```

Nothing changes, the error persists

Comment: Umm... I meant use something *other than* `reflect-metadata`, e.g. `"reflect-metadata": "Reflect"`.

Comment: @double-beep nah, does not work on whatever variants I try, including yours...

Comment: Do you get the same error? On what pages? I tried those in [this repository of yours](https://github.com/Kenya-West/userscript-typescript-template-kw) without any issues.

Comment: @double-beep thanks, that's the correct repo you have chosen. Please add the userscript contents you generated to Tampermonkey extension and then go to https://motherfuckingwebsite.com/ (just an HTML page, best for debugging) to see if this working? It should throw the error `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Object.defineProperty called on non-object`.

Comment: You say you load these two packages from jsDelivr. What are the links you pass to `@require`?

Comment: @double-beep 

```
// @require https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/reflect-metadata@0.1.13
// @require https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tsyringe@4.7.0
```

Comment: The tsyringe file you've linked tries to access an undefined `exports` variable and uses `require()`. Why do you want to include tsyringe via `@require` in the first place?

Comment: @double-beep because I want to have a lighter JS bundle

Comment: How is it lighter? The tsyringe is included, though in a separate bundle.

Comment: @double-beep thank you for help! I rethinked my question and decided there's no need to separate bundles and load some dynamically through Tampermonkey API. Because there is simply not much profit of it, if it has some. The question is closed I guess